# How to create a loop to "uncount" all dataframes in environment in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a very long list of imported dataframes that I have imported using:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

My resulting Data panel looks like this:
[All dataframes use same naming convention and data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhab5.png)

How would I create a for loop that applies column names to all of these, and then uses tidyr uncount?
For a single dataframe, I would use:

```
names(df) <- c("EVI", "Frequency", "Transition")
df_Tidy <- tidyr::uncount(df, Frequency)
```

How would I apply the previous block of code to all of the data frames in my Global Environment?

Comment: Are all your data.frames still stored in `myfiles`? If they're not, they should be. Then it would be as simple as `map`-ing or `lapply`-ing over your list - `lapply(myfiles, function(x) tidyr::uncount(x, Frequency) )` or something like that.

Comment: @thelatemail, I made a mistake during the submission.  I've since edited my post.

Comment: I'd go back to using the `myfiles` list. It will make processing many datasets like you want to do a **lot** easier than trying to use `assign` `get` and naming conventions etc.

Comment: @thelatemail, I'll do that.  The issue is that I am a total beginner at this and I'm not familiar with this format.  Having done this, when I run Ronak's code, I get: Error in names(x) <- c("EVI", "Frequency", "Transition") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: Something in your `myfiles` isn't a *data.frame* with 3 columns by the looks of that. Does `lengths(myfiles)` return 3 for every list item?

Comment: When I do that it returns 1 for all items in the list.  It's interesting because the .csv's are 3 columns.  In the imgur link lines 1-2 return "myfiles" while lines 4-5 return individual dataframes.  The former returns 1, while the latter all have 3 variables.  https://imgur.com/pRfj0d4

Comment: You're using `read.delim` instead of `read.csv` in the `lapply` version, which means it won't import properly as it's not finding the `,` separators. Change that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @thelatemail, OK that worked!  One last thing.  When I imported them as dataframes (the discouraged method), the names were the same as the .csv.  When I imported them as lists the names changed, they have new_files[[1]] and new_files[[2]].  How do I which item in the list corresponds to which original .csv?

Comment: Each item of the list should be named after your input `temp` vector. So `new_files[["L8_eviblah_csv"]]` or something should allow you to access the bit you want by name. Try `names(new_files)` to see all the names.

Comment: @thelatemail, I get it now!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply`/`map` :

```
new_files <- lapply(myfiles, function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("EVI", "Frequency", "Transition")
  tidyr::uncount(x, Frequency)
})
```